# What are some good resources on the theory of non linear systems of ordinary differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a thesis where the author works on the system: $$k' = kl + 1$$ $$l'=-k^2 + \beta^2$$ where $\beta$ is a constant and there are some terms and definitions I haven't seen before, so I'm looking to catch up on that.

Comment: "Dynamical system" is the key word. [Hubbard and West](https://books.google.fr/books?id=e5K786f9qPkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a classic reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer was already posted in the comments.